# Get records for the maximum count grouped results among all group

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql.js

I have three tables book, member, and loan. I want to **find the firstname, lastname and title of the books which member has maximum number of books**. I tried the following

1. To get the member who has maximum records, I grouped the records based on member_id and it decending the order to get the max count. The grouped record contains only one member_id(3) but I want all member_id (2 and 3) to get the "title of the book" so I used GROUP_CONCAT to get it.

```
SELECT m.firstname, m.lastname, l.member_id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.book_id) as book_id, count(*) as max_c from member m
join loan l
ON m.member_id = l.member_id
group by l.member_id
order by max_c desc limit 1
```

2. Then I tried to get the desired records using the below query

```
SELECT m.firstname, m.lastname, b.title from book b
join loan l ON b.book_id = l.book_id
where l.book_id IN
(SELECT m.firstname, m.lastname, l.member_id, GROUP_CONCAT(l.book_id) as book_id, count(*) as max_c from member m
join loan l
ON m.member_id = l.member_id
group by l.member_id
order by max_c desc limit 1)
```

The desired output is
The output is expected as given below

```
firstname   lastname    title
Mark        Sacks       The Cow 
Mark        Sacks       XML for beginners
```

I'm trying this in SQLite(SQL.js) in sqlfiddle pls help me to achieve this.

**book** table

```
book_id     isbn            title               author      publish_year
1           444222666325    Mars                Mark Sas    2001
2           784566512135    The Cow             Williams    1996
3           488984115444    XML for beginners   Jake Snow   2005
4           544465545655    Into Thin Air       Jon Kraka   1990
5           878745656513    And Tango Makes     PeterParnel 1956
6           564564123213    Swimmy  Leo         Lionni      2010
7           132125645678    XML and XQuery      Lee Cakes   2014
8           132154548746    Happy Places        Steve Zus   1998
9           788897998754    The Mascot          Kevin Bacon 1987
10          878561132116    XQuery for begin    Virginia    1800
```

**member** table

```
member_id   lastname    firstname
1001        Smith       John
2123        Sacks       Mark    
3456        Johnson     Susan   
4223        States      Nick    
5987        Stew        Martha
```

**loan** table

```
member_id   book_id loan_date   due_date
5987           4    2017-09-13  2017-09-30
2123           3    2017-09-13  2017-09-15
4223           9    2017-09-13  2019-09-13
1001           5    2017-10-15  2017-10-19
2123           2    2017-10-15  2017-11-15
```

Comment: Does the due date of the books need to be considered here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `COUNT` here as an analytic function, to retain all rows, then apply `RANK` to find the highest ranking author along with all records:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT m.firstname, m.lastname, b.title, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY m.member_id) cnt
    FROM member m
    INNER JOIN loan l ON l.member_id = m.member_id
    INNER JOIN book b ON b.book_id = l.book_id
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) rnk
    FROM cte
)

SELECT firstname, lastname, title
FROM cte2
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The query looks fine and I tried it on SQLite (SQL.js) by modifying according to it but didn't work.

Comment: @Sudhakar Check my updated answer which includes a demo.  The query is working per your expectations.  If you modified my answer to something else, then it is up to you to fix that.

Comment: Yes, @Tim Biegeleisen. I'm trying in the sqlfiddle (SQLite (SQL.js)). Thanks.